# Azure DevOps add a comment using the Python API

Tags: python, azure, api, devops

Looked everywhere for help with this but with no success.

I'm using this https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api and would like to post a comment on a DevOps work item.

So far I managed this:

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import pprint
from azure.devops.v5_1.work_item_tracking.models import Wiql
from vsts.work_item_tracking.v4_1.models.json_patch_operation import JsonPatchOperation

# Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
personal_access_token = 'P_A_T'
organization_url = 'https://xxxx.visualstudio.com'

# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

# Get a client (the "core" client provides access to projects, teams, etc)
core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()

wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()

patch_document = [
    JsonPatchOperation(
        op="add",
        path="/fields/System.History",
        value={
            "text": "Hey StackOverFlow! Please help me",
        },
    )
]

wit_client.update_work_item(patch_document, "1550")
```

But running this I get the following error:

```
msrest.exceptions.ClientRequestError: Error occurred in request., RetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxxx.visualstudio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /_apis/wit/workItems/1550 (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses'))
```

What am I doing wrong, why isn't it working :)? Please help me SOF!

Comment: According to the .NET documentation - `value` argument should be a `str` in your `JsonPatchOperation` payload. So `value='some string'` - Haven't used this or seen it in action before but took a quick look at the docs hence the comment.

Comment: Moreoever, judging by the response: "too many 500 error responses" indicates poorly written server-side code. HTTP 500 indicates server-side error, which is not the case here. If you could attempt the same command through the CLI you might get a better response. (e.g. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/40361)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @tortal, I guess its the value that is wrong. You need to pass the string as value.
**And also the id should be of type "int" and not string.**

```
wit_client.update_work_item(patch_document, 1550)
```

To help you, there is a method provided by azure-devops, "add_comment" where you pass your text as a parameter. Maybe you can use that.

```
req = CommentCreate(text="Hey StackOverFlow! Please help me")
work_item_client.add_comment(request=req, project='XXXX', work_item_id=1550)
```